# localhost loading forever .asp.net waiting for localhost forever read it but not working

Tags: iis, localhost, load, port

I was coding on the script side and I was testing it. I finished my project and added it to the folder where the physical path is located, but localhost is being installed continuously and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. Did you get a problem while publishing？How did you publish the application? Have you get any error messages?

Comment: I did not encounter a problem while publishing.
I published the application via iis. I had a web.config permission error before this loading error, and the problem was resolved when I gave the necessary permissions.